# JPA-Eclipse link, use Composite Persistence Units without <jar-file>

Tags: java, database, jpa, eclipselink, persistence-unit

I need to use two difrent databases, with relation in entities between them. I want to have all entities in on project and use Composite Persistence Unit to manage which entity will be storen on which database. Is this possible? I found only example with one Composite Persistence Unit and Composite Persistence Unit members in difrent jars. If my idea is not possible what i need to do, to compile persistence units to jars? I need to put in this jar Entitiy classes too? What about relations between this entities?

Comment: generally you would have two persistence units, one for each database, that you then combine into a single composite persistence unit.  There are no restrictions on where entities go - you can have multiple persistence units in the same jar file, or spread out among many.  If you are going to have multiple PUs in the same jar, just be sure to list out the classes that belong to each and make sure there is no overlap, or it they cannot be used in a composite Persistence unit.  see http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/usingmultipledbs.htm

Comment: I cant find any example of one persistence.xml with Composite Persistence Unit and Composite Persistence Unit Member i it, i fidn only Composite Persistence Unit and Composite Persistence Unit Member in jar files. Can you show me example with one  persistence.xml and all of Composite Persistence and members in it?

Comment: I don't have any off hand.  Try it first and show the problems you get.

Comment: I decide to use one big database isntead of 2 difrent and composite PU, but thanks for answer.